# c++ OpenCV Rect size increasing

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to learn how cv::Rect() works.
I have a 200x200 image and I'd like break this image into 3x3 rectangles.
Here's my code:

```
for(int y = 0; y < img.rows; y+=3;) // img.rows = 200
{
    for(int x =0; x < img.cols; x+=3){ // img.cols = 200
        cv:: Rect my_region = cv::Rect(x, y, x + 3, y + 3);
        Mat my_mat = img(my_region).clone();
        int mat_Size = mymat.total(); 
        cout << "region size: " << mat_Size << endl;
        if(x==6){  // test up to 6
           return - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

mat_size should be consistently 9 because I am generating 3x3 rectangles. However, it's actually increasing by 9 every time: 9 -> 18 -> 27. Which is not what I intended to do. How do I fix it? Please help.

Comment: You're giving `x+3,y+3` as width and height to [`cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#a5a41149f4b012b9f323b5913454375a1). So as the values of x and y increases so do the dimensions of your rectangles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `cv::Rect(x, y, x + 3, y + 3);` is not in your sense because the last parameters does not mean the coordinates of lower right corner of the Rectangle as you are thinking. Having a look at the [OpenCV doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#a5a41149f4b012b9f323b5913454375a1) or into [`types.hpp`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L1765), you will have

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
Rect_<_Tp>::Rect_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y, _Tp _width, _Tp _height)
: x(_x), y(_y), width(_width), height(_height) {}
```

The last 2 parameters stands for width and height of the Rectangle, so to fix your code, you will need
`cv::Rect my_region = cv::Rect(x, y, 3, 3);`